# fullcalendar does not change backgoundcolor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar

I am using `fullcalendar` on ruby on rails and it is working really well. I am trying to change the `backgound_color` property of an event but I can't see how to get it. I was able to change the border color.

My JSON looks like:

```
[

    {
        "_routes": null,
        "title": "this should be red",
        "color": "#2308d1",
        "url": "/events/59",
        "start": "2013-06-18T00:00:00-05:00",
        "end": "2013-06-18T22:59:59-05:00",
        "allDay": false,
        "event_id": 59,
        "background_color": "red"
    },
]
```

I want to make something nice to share with the community and the source is here 
https://github.com/mzararagoza/rails-fullcalendar-icecube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to use backgroundColor not background_color.

https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/1009caf3b792ad5958d0660ebcfee49fad6f7026/src/util.js

Answer (score 2):

You can define for each type of events a classname, like this:

```
[            
   url: ajaxcallURL(_url,"6"),
   type: 'POST',                                
  //error: function() { alert('something broke with courses...'); },
   data:{                                                                   
   'func':func,
   'year':y
     },
   cache: false,              
   color: '#FF931E', //This is the color for the events
   textColor: 'white'
   className: 'myCssClassName' //in the Css you can use the class to set the background color for the events, i think this overrides color property.                                    
]
```

Or were you thinking about table cell color? Cause this is something completly diferent...